# Recalculate VBA formula excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to find a solution to automatically recalculate a VBA formula once I change the color of the cell

```
Function SumColorColumns11(sumRange As Range) As Double

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In sumRange
If cell.Interior.Color = 12611584 And cell.Column = 7 Then
SumColorColumns11 = SumColorColumns11 + 20
ElseIf cell.Interior.Color = 12611584 And cell.Column = 8 Then
SumColorColumns11 = SumColorColumns11 + 30
    End If
    Next cell
     SumColorColumns11 = SumColorColumns11 / 100
```

Currently when I want to recalculate the VBA formula I go to a cell that has the formula and click on the then formula then press enter.

After editing it

```
 Function SumColorColumns11(sumRange As Range) As Double

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In sumRange
If cell.Interior.Color = 12611584 And cell.Column = 7 Then
SumColorColumns11 = SumColorColumns11 + 20
ElseIf cell.Interior.Color = 12611584 And cell.Column = 8 Then
SumColorColumns11 = SumColorColumns11 + 30
cell.Calculate        
End If
        Next cell
         SumColorColumns11 = SumColorColumns11 / 100
```

I have found other solution to Run a Macro when a User Changes, but I don't know how to apply it on my function as it receive an range and return a value.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C6:R393")) Is Nothing Then

MsgBox "hi"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Calculate` should force calculation on a page to update

Comment: You can also use range calculate method: in your case cell.Calculate

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 thanks, but where shall I add ActiveSheet.Calculate in my code?

Comment: @MichalPalko thanks, but how can I do the  range calculate method?

Comment: I guess in your case before End If

Comment: @MichalPalko I have added cell.Calculate before End If and then change a color of the cell and the percentage hasn't been updated.

Comment: What do you mean by formula? Is it live excel formula? Or hard-coded?

Comment: @MichalPalko I have created a hard-coded from VBA.

Comment: What part of your code is that formula?

Comment: How do you use this function? Do you call it from excel cell or use it in another vba code?

Comment: @MichalPalko the whole of the code, which when I enter =SumColorColumns11 in a cell and click enter the percentage is updated.

Comment: Ok, that changes a lot. There are multiple ways how to do it. Easiest way is to add sheet event (trigger macro when  something in sheet changes).

Comment: @MichalPalko how can I do it?

Comment: Check the answer.

Comment: @MichalPalko same its not working, once I change a cell color

Comment: There is no event which is triggered when you change a cell's color.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that, there is no event fired when the cell color is changed, also a recalculate does not work on the UDF - as you say you have to manually trigger it - so I suspect the best you can do is to call a one liner of your code from some other frequently triggered event - I suggest the SelectionChange event - as follows

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   ' Change A1 in the following to the Cell you want the result in
   Range("A1").Value = SumColorColumns11(Range("G1:H9"))  ' Change G1:H9 to your own range here
End Sub
```

Then just moving to a different cell will trigger it after you change the color - not ideal of course, so not the answer you're looking for, but it's a crude workaround.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ADDED ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

The following added in response to your comment for values in multiple rows and to reduce the frequency of calling the routine

Put this in the Sheets Module Declaration Area

```
Public LastRng As Range, CalledB4 As Boolean
```

Then this is the modified SelectionChange Event Code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    '
    ' This routine will write a value into Column A that is the sum of the colors in cells G & H of the same row
    ' It only calls your SumColorColumns11 when we moved out of a cell in the WatchRng (G2:H12)
    '
    Const WatchRng  As String = "G2:H12"
    Dim xCel As Range, Rng2Chek As Range
    
    If Not (CalledB4 = True) Then
       CalledB4 = True
    Else
       If Not Application.Intersect(Range(WatchRng), LastRng) Is Nothing Then
          For Each xCel In Application.Intersect(Range(WatchRng), LastRng).Cells
             ' The following line checks Columns G&H of the same row as xCel - for a different range change G & H
             Set Rng2Chek = Range("G" & xCel.Row & ":H" & xCel.Row)
             ' The 1 in the following line means put result in column A - use 2 for B, 3 for C etc
             xCel.Offset(0, 1 - xCel.Column).Value = SumColorColumns11(Rng2Chek)
          Next xCel
       End If
    End If
    Set LastRng = Target
End Sub
```

Comment: Its working, thanks!, but "A1" is not fixed my function will apply in each row with fixed Column.

Comment: You can just repeat that line for every row with a different cell in place of A1 - or put it in a loop

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways of setting a cell's interior colour and the methods I tried to develop to find out if one of them was applied all ended up being more voluminous than the simplest of all solutions, which is to calculate the totals frequently. The event procedure below does that - almost. Please try it.

Install the procedure below in the code module of the worksheet on which you want the action (**Not** the module in which your UDF resides!)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const WatchCol  As Long = 12611584
    Const WatchRng  As String = "G2:H12"
    Const ResultRng As String = "G13:H13"
    
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range(WatchRng), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Range(ResultRng).Calculate
    End If
End Sub
```

There are two ranges to define. The `WatchRng` is equal to your function's *SumRange*. My procedure will respond to clicks in that range. The `ResultRng` is the range to be recalculated. It's where your UDFs are being called. In fact, this range will be recalculated every time you click anywhere in the `WatchRng`. However, it's possible to change a cell's colour without clicking anything. In such cases the next click within the `WatchRng` will trigger the calculation. Accepting this flaw is less burdensome, I judged, than having a long procedure running at every click that would cure the flaw but make your sheet react sluggishly.

While trying out many ideas I also reviewed your UDF. Since it will be called more often I tried to streamline it. However, it has no functionality your own design doesn't also have.

```
Function SumColorColumns11(SumRange As Range) As Double

    Dim Fun     As Double
    Dim Cell    As Range
    
    For Each Cell In SumRange
        If Cell.Interior.Color = 12611584 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Fun = Fun + Array(0.2, 0.3)(Cell.Column - 7)
        End If
    Next Cell
    SumColorColumns11 = Fun
End Function
```

Comment: It's working. I know because I tested it. So, the question is why you can't make it work for you. Any hints? Care to tell me what you tested? Which procedure doesn't want to work for you? Where did you install the event procedure?

Comment: I copied and pasted the code and when I change to color of the cell the the watch range nothing has happen.

Comment: I tried the following, put various colors into G2:G11 and similar (not same) in H2:H11 then put UDF in G13 & H13 it correctly showed 0.2 in G13 and 0.3 in H13  BUT when I cleared all colors from column G and moved selection the 0.2 remained - so didn't fully work for me either

Comment: @Variatus It worked when I replaced a countable color with any non countable color BY COPYING a Cell to overwrite the color. BUT NOT when I just assign a color from the Excel Toolbar/Menu

Comment: The ***only*** countable colour is #12611584 throughout the code, yours and mine. Any colour of different number is different even if it looks the same on your monitor. Monitors can't display all colours and settle for similar ones. You can get the colour of any seel by selecting it and entering `? ActiveCell.Interior.Color` in the immediate window. If you need to count different colours and, in consequence, need to track different colour numbers please ask another question. This one can't be expanded that far.